# symfony id is adding 1 when i use path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have this button in twig

```
<input type="submit" formaction="{{path('redirect',{'id': l.id , 'page': i , 'w': 2})}}" value=" 
{{ i + 1 }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
```

the id must be 371 but wen i go to the controller with this route:

```
/** 
 * @Route("/gerer/exam/passer_exam/redirection{id}{page}{w}" , name="redirect")
*/
```

and i dump the variable id in this function :

```
public function rediriger (int $id,int $page , int $w , Request $request ,
    EntityManagerInterface $manager ,ExamQuestionRepository $repo)
```

it show that the id is 3711

Answer (score 1):

Little tip for you ..You don't need a form to do this. You just do this:

for twig:

```
 <buton href="{{ path('redirect' , {'id': l.id , 'page': i , 'w': 2}) }}" >  </button>
```

or  if you use bootstrap:

```
 <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ path('redirect' , {'id': l.id , 'page': i , 'w': 2}) }}" >  </a>
```

And you'd have to correct the route as Craigh suggests:

```
/** 
 * @Route("/gerer/exam/passer_exam/redirection/{id}/{page}/{w}" , name="redirect")
 */
```

Comment: thnx that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
/** 
 * @Route("/gerer/exam/passer_exam/redirection/{id}/{page}/{w}" , name="redirect")
*/
```

My assumption is that $page is 1 and so `{id}{page}` is giving you 3711.
maybe re-read https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad I could help. My repo points would appreciate you marking this as the answer if it answered your question.